# How to output signal when someone stands on a pressure plate for three seconds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm making a map where players have to stand on a pressure plate for three seconds before the dragon is spawned. Is there a way to make it so the *only* way to output a signal is when you stand on the pressure plate for three seconds in a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this contraption, where the output is the redstone torch on the right.

[image]

But make sure the hoppers face into each other!

[image]

How does it work? In the default state the hopper with the items in it is locked, so the items stay in it. When you step on the pressure plate the front hopper gets unlocked and the back one locked, so items start flowing out of the front one. Once the front hopper is empty (after about 3 seconds) the comparator turns off, allowing the redstone torch to turn on.

Comment: Will this work multiple times without needing to be manually reset?

Comment: @hyperviper11 Yes, this will reset itself after 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks so much this is really clever. I would never had thought of it! +1

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you! :)

Comment: Wait, this will work if you stand on the pressure pate for two seconds, then stand off for one second, and then stand back for 2 seconds. This does work, and is compact, but isn't exactly how the OP wanted it. (I would like the OP, @hyperviper11 to see this too)

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this which could be easily edited if your need change in the future would be to have a circuit connected to the pressure plate where.
If the plate is off it runs a fast clock resetting a scoreboard variable to 0.
If the plate is on it runs a one second clock (10 redstone ticks) which increases the value of the scoreboard variable by one.

When the variable is equal to 3 the dragon spawns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screenshot:

[image: 3-second signal detector]

The contraption above will output a signal (power the command block) only when all torches from the upper part are off. All the torches will be off only when all the repeaters are on, and they are on only when you step on the pressure plate for 3 seconds exactly (7 repeaters on maximum, 0.4 second delay, one on half delay - preferably the first).

For extra precision, you can place more repeaters with smaller delays, so even when you step off for a small fraction of a second, you will have to start again:

[image: another RS contraption]
(all repeaters set to 0.2 seconds delay)

[image: Doing it wrong]
(all repeaters set to minimum delay)

The screenshot above shows a redundant way of doing this, though the upgraded version of it looks good:

[image: Shiny!]
Just added a floor with redstone lamps.

Your main problem here are not the Repeater delays, but the pressure plate delay - it stops sending signal a bit later then you step off of it.

Comment: Cool! Works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AND gate with the following configuration: output signal spawns the dragon (right); 2 input signals: one from the pressure plate (lower left), another from the pressure plate, but delayed by 3 seconds using several repeaters (upper left). The output will only be turned on if the pressure plate is currently pressed and was pressed 3 seconds ago too.

[image: Redstone circuit scheme]

Comment: @hyperviper11 and Raul, this will also work if you step on the pressure plate once and then in 3 seconds again. This does not fully answer the OP's question.

Comment: Is your left and right switched?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Rudolf edited my answer, right and left are switched, fixed.

Comment: The more upvoted answer has a bigger problem. You can step 1 second, go do somethign else, and step another second, times are accumulative but op wants 3 seconds in a row.